# Parametric gnuplot Scripts

Tags: shell, plot, gnuplot

When I try to write a shell script such as

```
gnuplot
cd '/home/cagirici/test'
plot "case1.test" with linespoints
```

and run it in `sudo`, the script stops after running gnuplot.

In each .test file, I have 12 columns. I won't plot them all at once but choose what to plot. For instance, if I choose to plot the `success percentage`, it should plot `1:2` and `1:8`. But if I choose `error percentage`, it should plot `1:4` and `1:10` (it is basically `i:(i+6)`.)

I need to write a scripts that takes two inputs: i) file name ii) what to plot.

Notice that I also want to choose the line type, point type and output shell. (if there is a configuration to set specific line and point types as default values, please tell me this as well)

Can I write this script in Ubuntu? Or should I use a different method.

My script would look something like

```
case "$2" in
("success percentage") plot "$1" using 1:2, plot "$1" using 1:8
("error percentage") plot "$1" using 1:4, plot "$1" using 1:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this work by creating a Gnuplot script with variables and then passing values to these variables at run time from command line or your bash script.

Lets call the Gnuplot script `Myscript.gp`:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'graph.png'

plot file u x:y w linespoints
```

Here `file` and `x:y` can be varried when you invoke Gnuplot from your bash script. A possible call to `Myscript.gp` is as follows:

```
gnuplot -e "x=1;y=2;file = \"mydata.dat\"" Myscript.gp
```

In the snippet of your bash script that you provide this may look like:

```
case "$2" in
("success percentage") gnuplot -e "x=1; y=2; file = \"$1\"" Myscript.gp
```

Below I'm also providing a dummy `mydata.dat` file which you can use to try things.

```
1.54    23.66   43.66
1.75    26.25   46.25
1.92    30.20   40.20
2.08    34.46   44.46
2.44    42.08   42.08
2.78    46.81   46.81
3.03    51.10   41.10
3.70    52.99   42.99
4.17    56.15   46.15
4.76    59.34   49.34
```

If you are calculating the column numbers (`x` and `y`) in your bash script then you can also use variables inside the plot command.

```
gnuplot -e "x=$x;y=$y;file = \"mydata.dat\"" Myscript.gp
```

Below I show the output once using:

```
gnuplot -e "x=1;y=2;file = \"mydata.dat\"" Myscript.gp
```

and once

```
gnuplot -e "x=1;y=3;file = \"mydata.dat\"" Myscript.gp
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar problem 2 years back, then my senior team members decided to write a tool for plotting graphs using a simple csv and plotting specifications and tool will plot graphs for you,

Initially it was designed for sar data on linux so named RSAR but in general it is a csv plotter.)
if required you can contact me nachiket.kate90@gmail.com